# How can I get a java.io.InputStream from a java.lang.String?

Tags: java, string, inputstream

I have a `String` that I want to use as an `InputStream`. In Java 1.0, you could use [`java.io.StringBufferInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html), but that has been `@Deprecrated` (with good reason--you cannot specify the character set encoding):

> This class does not properly convert
> characters into bytes. As of JDK 1.1,
> the preferred way to create a stream
> from a string is via the `StringReader`
> class.

You can create a [`java.io.Reader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) with [`java.io.StringReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html), but there are no adapters to take a `Reader` and create an `InputStream`.

I found an [ancient bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4217782) asking for a suitable replacement, but no such thing exists--as far as I can tell.

The oft-suggested workaround is to use [`java.lang.String.getBytes()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)) as input to [`java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html):

```
public InputStream createInputStream(String s, String charset)
    throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException {

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes(charset));
}
```

but that means materializing the entire `String` in memory as an array of bytes, and defeats the purpose of a stream. In most cases this is not a big deal, but I was looking for something that would preserve the intent of a stream--that as little of the data as possible is (re)materialized in memory.

Answer (score 78):

**Update:** This answer is precisely what the OP doesn't want. Please read the other answers.

For those cases when we don't care about the data being re-materialized in memory, please use:

```
new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: The solution proposed by this answer has been anticipated, contemplated upon, and rejected by the question. So in my opinion, this answer should be deleted.

Comment: You might be right. I originally made it a comment probably because it wasn't an actual answer to OP's question.

Comment: As a visitor coming here because of the question title, I am happy that this answer is here.  So: Please don't delete this answer. The remark at the top "This answer is precisely what the OP doesn't want. Please read the other answers." is sufficient.

Comment: As of java7:
`new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`

Answer (score 19):

If you don't mind a dependency on the [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) package, then you could use the [IOUtils.toInputStream(String text)](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#line.1190) method.

Comment: In that case you add a dependency which does nothing else than `return new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());' Is that really worth a dependency? In all honesty, no - it isn't.

Comment: True, besides it is exactly the workaround the op doesn't wan't to use because the he does not want to "materialize the string into memory" oposed to the string being materialized somewhere else in the system :)

Comment: Do we have any library which converts custom object into source of input stream; something like IOUtils.toInputStream(MyObject object)?

Answer (score 6):

There is an adapter from Apache Commons-IO which adapts from Reader to InputStream, which is named [ReaderInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReaderInputStream.html).

Example code:

```
@Test
public void testReaderInputStream() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = new ReaderInputStream(new StringReader("largeString"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Assert.assertEquals("largeString", IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909221/5658642

Answer (score 3):

To my mind, the easiest way to do this is by pushing the data through a Writer:

```
public class StringEmitter {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    class DataHandler extends OutputStream {
      @Override
      public void write(final int b) throws IOException {
        write(new byte[] { (byte) b });
      }
      @Override
      public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        write(b, 0, b.length);
      }
      @Override
      public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len)
          throws IOException {
        System.out.println("bytecount=" + len);
      }
    }

    StringBuilder sample = new StringBuilder();
    while (sample.length() < 100 * 1000) {
      sample.append("sample");
    }

    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
        new DataHandler(), "UTF-16");
    writer.write(sample.toString());
    writer.close();
  }
}
```

The JVM implementation I'm using pushed data through in 8K chunks, but you could have some affect on the buffer size by reducing the number of characters written at one time and calling flush.

---

An alternative to writing your own CharsetEncoder wrapper to use a Writer to encode the data, though it is something of a pain to do right. This should be a reliable (if inefficient) implementation:

```
/** Inefficient string stream implementation */
public class StringInputStream extends InputStream {

  /* # of characters to buffer - must be >=2 to handle surrogate pairs */
  private static final int CHAR_CAP = 8;

  private final Queue<Byte> buffer = new LinkedList<Byte>();
  private final Writer encoder;
  private final String data;
  private int index;

  public StringInputStream(String sequence, Charset charset) {
    data = sequence;
    encoder = new OutputStreamWriter(
        new OutputStreamBuffer(), charset);
  }

  private int buffer() throws IOException {
    if (index >= data.length()) {
      return -1;
    }
    int rlen = index + CHAR_CAP;
    if (rlen > data.length()) {
      rlen = data.length();
    }
    for (; index < rlen; index++) {
      char ch = data.charAt(index);
      encoder.append(ch);
      // ensure data enters buffer
      encoder.flush();
    }
    if (index >= data.length()) {
      encoder.close();
    }
    return buffer.size();
  }

  @Override
  public int read() throws IOException {
    if (buffer.size() == 0) {
      int r = buffer();
      if (r == -1) {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    return 0xFF & buffer.remove();
  }

  private class OutputStreamBuffer extends OutputStream {

    @Override
    public void write(int i) throws IOException {
      byte b = (byte) i;
      buffer.add(b);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, one possible way is to:

- Create a [`PipedOutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html)
- Pipe it to a [`PipedInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html)
- Wrap an [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) around the `PipedOutputStream` (you can specify the encoding in the constructor)
- Et voilá, anything you write to the `OutputStreamWriter` can be read from the `PipedInputStream`!

Of course, this seems like a rather hackish way to do it, but at least it is a way.

Comment: Interesting... of course, with this solution I believe that you would either materialize the whole string in memory, or suffer starvation on the reading thread. Still hoping that there's a real implementation somewhere.

Comment: You have to be careful with Piped(Input|Output)Stream.  As per the docs: "...Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not recommended, as it may deadlock the thread..."  http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to roll your own, creating an `InputStream` implementation that likely would use `java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder` to encode each `char` or chunk of `char`s to an array of bytes for the `InputStream` as necessary.

Comment: Doing things one character at a time is expensive. That's why we have "chunked iterators" like InputStream that allow us to read a buffer at a time.

Comment: I agree with Tom -- you **really** don't want to do this one character at a time.

Comment: Unless the data is really small, and other things (network latency, for example) take longer. Then it doesn't matter. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any possibility with pure JDK means. The [StringBufferInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html) is deprecated because it does not convert characters into bytes properly.
If Guava library is available in the project, the internal [ReaderInputStream](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/io/ReaderInputStream.java) can be used via:

```
public InputStream asInputStream(CharSequence chars, Charset charset) throws IOException {
    return CharSource.wrap(chars).asByteSource(charset).openStream();
}
```

Under the hood the *CharSequence*/*String* is wrapped into a *Reader* which in turn is wrapped into the *InputStream* mentioned in the beginning. This allows the conversion via streaming.

Answer (score -1):

You can take help of org.hsqldb.lib library.

```
public StringInputStream(String paramString)
  {
    this.str = paramString;
    this.available = (paramString.length() * 2);
  }
```

Comment: Generally, questions are much more useful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old question but I had the same problem myself today, and this was my solution:

```
public static InputStream getStream(final CharSequence charSequence) {
 return new InputStream() {
  int index = 0;
  int length = charSequence.length();
  @Override public int read() throws IOException {
   return index>=length ? -1 : charSequence.charAt(index++);
  }
 };
}
```