# Which encoding opens CSV files correctly with Excel on both Mac and Windows?

Tags: windows, excel, macos, csv, utf

We have a web app that exports CSV files containing foreign characters with UTF-8, no BOM. Both Windows and Mac users get garbage characters in Excel. I tried converting to UTF-8 with BOM; Excel/Win is fine with it, Excel/Mac shows gibberish. I'm using Excel 2003/Win, Excel 2011/Mac.
Here's all the encodings I tried:

```
Encoding  BOM      Win                            Mac
--------  ---      ----------------------------   ------------
utf-8     --       scrambled                      scrambled
utf-8     BOM      WORKS                          scrambled
utf-16    --       file not recognized            file not recognized
utf-16    BOM      file not recognized            Chinese gibberish
utf-16LE  --       file not recognized            file not recognized
utf-16LE  BOM      characters OK,                 same as Win
                   row data all in first field
```

The best one is UTF-16LE with BOM, but the CSV is not recognized as such. The field separator is comma, but semicolon doesn't change things.

**Is there any encoding that works in both worlds?**

Comment: What if you use UTF-16LE for all the field data but use the 8bit/ASCII character for the comma?  Based on this article (http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm#CSVAndEncodings), Excel might be interpreting the Unicode comma as part of the field data instead of the separator.

Comment: Interesting tip @jveazey. I'll try this: `mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-16LE");` in my export code and post the results here.

Comment: Not that this helps you, but I tested Excel 2007 SP2 on Windows (using Notepad2 to create the test files).  Everything worked except UTF-16LE BOM (same result as yours on Windows) and UTF-16BE BOM (which parsed fields correctly but the BOM was included as the first 2 characters in A1).

Comment: Also, found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files

Comment: @hveazey, the quoted question has an answer by creechy recommending codepage Windows-1252. That didn't work for my case (German umlauts and sharp s).

Comment: @notJim, there's an answer by Jasdeep Gosal over on stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802, supposed to work for Mac and PC; I haven't tried it yet. He offers PHPExcel (which needs too much memory for me) and a TSV solution, but I need CSV.

Comment: I'm pretty skeptical of that solution, as I tried UTF-8 with a BOM amongst other solutions, and IIRC (I may be wrong) it didn't work. In any case: a) the performance issues would be a deal-killer for me, and b) it's not really my problem anymore anyway :) [for now at least...]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The lowdown is: There is no solution. Excel 2011/Mac cannot correctly interpret a CSV file containing umlauts and diacritical marks no matter what encoding or hoop jumping you do. I'd be glad to hear someone tell me different!

Comment: I found the WIN-1252 or ISO-8859-1 encodings to be working. Please see my answer.

Comment: The solution is to use UTF-16LE and ensure that your using tabs to separate columns instead of commas.

Comment: Did you really try this on Win and Mac Tim? As I mentioned, TSV is not an option in my case.

Comment: For me, export works fine if I use WIN-1252 encoding, both on Mac and on Windows versions of Excel. @Timm, you should consider changing the accepted answer.

Comment: For those that found this working, did you actually have extended (like chinese) characters in your datasets?  The WIN-1252 encoding breaks on those because they are out of range.

Comment: WIN-1252 doesn't work exporting "Curaçao" on Excel 2010.

Answer (score 63):

### Excel Encodings

I found the `WINDOWS-1252` encoding to be the least frustrating when dealing with Excel. Since its basically Microsofts own proprietary character set, one can assume it will work on both the Mac and the Windows version of MS-Excel. Both versions at least include a corresponding "File origin" or "File encoding" selector which correctly reads the data.

Depending on your system and the tools you use, this encoding could also be named `CP1252`, `ANSI`, `Windows (ANSI)`, `MS-ANSI` or just `Windows`, among other variations.

This encoding is a superset of `ISO-8859-1` (aka `LATIN1` and others), so you can fallback to `ISO-8859-1` if you cannot use `WINDOWS-1252` for some reason. Be advised that `ISO-8859-1` is missing some characters from `WINDOWS-1252` as shown here:

```
| Char | ANSI | Unicode | ANSI Hex | Unicode Hex | HTML entity | Unicode Name                               | Unicode Range            |
| €    | 128  | 8364    | 0x80     | U+20AC      | &euro;      | euro sign                                  | Currency Symbols         |
| ‚    | 130  | 8218    | 0x82     | U+201A      | &sbquo;     | single low-9 quotation mark                | General Punctuation      |
| ƒ    | 131  | 402     | 0x83     | U+0192      | &fnof;      | Latin small letter f with hook             | Latin Extended-B         |
| „    | 132  | 8222    | 0x84     | U+201E      | &bdquo;     | double low-9 quotation mark                | General Punctuation      |
| …    | 133  | 8230    | 0x85     | U+2026      | &hellip;    | horizontal ellipsis                        | General Punctuation      |
| †    | 134  | 8224    | 0x86     | U+2020      | &dagger;    | dagger                                     | General Punctuation      |
| ‡    | 135  | 8225    | 0x87     | U+2021      | &Dagger;    | double dagger                              | General Punctuation      |
| ˆ    | 136  | 710     | 0x88     | U+02C6      | &circ;      | modifier letter circumflex accent          | Spacing Modifier Letters |
| ‰    | 137  | 8240    | 0x89     | U+2030      | &permil;    | per mille sign                             | General Punctuation      |
| Š    | 138  | 352     | 0x8A     | U+0160      | &Scaron;    | Latin capital letter S with caron          | Latin Extended-A         |
| ‹    | 139  | 8249    | 0x8B     | U+2039      | &lsaquo;    | single left-pointing angle quotation mark  | General Punctuation      |
| Œ    | 140  | 338     | 0x8C     | U+0152      | &OElig;     | Latin capital ligature OE                  | Latin Extended-A         |
| Ž    | 142  | 381     | 0x8E     | U+017D      |             | Latin capital letter Z with caron          | Latin Extended-A         |
| ‘    | 145  | 8216    | 0x91     | U+2018      | &lsquo;     | left single quotation mark                 | General Punctuation      |
| ’    | 146  | 8217    | 0x92     | U+2019      | &rsquo;     | right single quotation mark                | General Punctuation      |
| “    | 147  | 8220    | 0x93     | U+201C      | &ldquo;     | left double quotation mark                 | General Punctuation      |
| ”    | 148  | 8221    | 0x94     | U+201D      | &rdquo;     | right double quotation mark                | General Punctuation      |
| •    | 149  | 8226    | 0x95     | U+2022      | &bull;      | bullet                                     | General Punctuation      |
| –    | 150  | 8211    | 0x96     | U+2013      | &ndash;     | en dash                                    | General Punctuation      |
| —    | 151  | 8212    | 0x97     | U+2014      | &mdash;     | em dash                                    | General Punctuation      |
| ˜    | 152  | 732     | 0x98     | U+02DC      | &tilde;     | small tilde                                | Spacing Modifier Letters |
| ™    | 153  | 8482    | 0x99     | U+2122      | &trade;     | trade mark sign                            | Letterlike Symbols       |
| š    | 154  | 353     | 0x9A     | U+0161      | &scaron;    | Latin small letter s with caron            | Latin Extended-A         |
| ›    | 155  | 8250    | 0x9B     | U+203A      | &rsaquo;    | single right-pointing angle quotation mark | General Punctuation      |
| œ    | 156  | 339     | 0x9C     | U+0153      | &oelig;     | Latin small ligature oe                    | Latin Extended-A         |
| ž    | 158  | 382     | 0x9E     | U+017E      |             | Latin small letter z with caron            | Latin Extended-A         |
| Ÿ    | 159  | 376     | 0x9F     | U+0178      | &Yuml;      | Latin capital letter Y with diaeresis      | Latin Extended-A         |
```

Note that the **euro sign is missing**.
This table can be found at [Alan Wood](http://www.alanwood.net/index.html).

### Conversion

Conversion is done differently in every tool and language. However, suppose you have a file `query_result.csv` which you know is `UTF-8` encoded. Convert it to `WINDOWS-1252` using `iconv`:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t WINDOWS-1252 query_result.csv > query_result-win.csv
```

Comment: A bit of a faff, but this does seem to be the answer for importing .csv files with european characters into Excel on Mac OSX

Comment: True. It answers the OP's question instead. In your case you would first have to know (or guess) the encoding used in your ".csv file with european characters". Then you can convert it to `WINDOS-1252`, which will most probably be correctly interpreted by both Mac and Windows Excel.

Comment: This is no real solution, sooner or later you will come across a character which is not convertible to WINDOWS-1252.

Comment: WINDOWS-1252 will fail if there is Chinese character. So it seems that UTF-16LE with BOM is the only option.

Comment: This works well for SQL data exports with diacritics.

Comment: @mikezter will it also work on Linux as well if not what is the common encoding for Windows  & Linux for CSV files. Thank You.

Comment: @swarna Yes, you can use iconv on Linux, too. Some tools on Linux might assume UTF-8 encoding on files of unknown origin. You can then either use iconv to convert them to UTF-8, or find a way to tell the tool in question which encoding your file uses.

Answer (score 27):

For UTF-16LE with BOM if you use tab characters as your delimiters instead of commas Excel will recognise the fields. The reason it works is that Excel actually ends up using its Unicode *.txt parser.

**Caveat**: If the file is edited in Excel and saved, it will be saved as tab-delimited ASCII. The problem now is that when you re-open the file Excel assumes it's real CSV (with commas), sees that it's not Unicode, so parses it as comma-delimited - and hence will make a hash of it!

**Update**: The above caveat doesn't appear to be happening for me today in Excel 2010 (Windows) at least, although there does appear to be a difference in saving behaviour if:

- you edit and quit Excel (tries to save as 'Unicode *.txt')

compared to:

- editing and closing *just the file* (works as expected).

Comment: Nice, but the caveat breaks the solution for me; the end users will not be happy with broken Excel sheets.

Comment: Possibly if you change the initial file extension to *.txt it would work, but then you lose association between the filetype and Excel: i.e. they can't double-click the file and have it open in Excel automatically.

Comment: That's won't work for me. Not being computer-savvy, the end user needs to open it in Excel without any hurdles.

Comment: I have my ".csv" Excel sheets looking good with special characters and separated fields.  I start my output string with "\ufeff" as a byte order mark (BOM), then using "\t" tabs in place of commas for field separation, and encoding the file with "utf-16LE".  Works like a charm, thanks to this page!

Comment: First line `sep=,` and UTF16LE encoding worked for me and did not require a different separator character (it remained to be comma). Opening the file by double-click loaded the file correctly, with special characters and line breaks within cells intact. Downside: the `sep=,` header is not recognized by any program except Excel as far as I've seen. But OpenOffice / LibreOffice do not require this hack anyway (line-breaks in cell contents work just fine, whereas loading from text file / using the text into columns assistant in Excel does not properly handle line breaks in cells).

Answer (score 12):

You only have tried comma-separated and semicolon-separated CSV. If you had tried tab-separated CSV (also called TSV) you would have found the answer:

**UTF-16LE** with **BOM** (byte order mark), **tab-separated**

---

**But**: In a comment you mention that TSV is not an option for you (I haven't been able to find this requirement in your question though). That's a pity. It often means that you allow manual editing of TSV files, which probably is not a good idea. Visual checking of TSV files is not a problem. Furthermore editors can be set to display a special character to mark tabs.

And yes, I tried this out on Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the clincher on importing utf8-encoded CSV into Excel 2011 for Mac: Microsoft says: "Excel for Mac does not currently support UTF-8." [Excel for Mac 2011 and UTF-8](http://x3ro.de/excel-mac-2011-utf8/)

Yay, way to go MS!

Answer (score 4):

The best workaround for reading CSV files with UTF-8 on Mac is to convert them into XLSX format. I have found a script made by Konrad Foerstner, which I have improved little bit by adding support for different delimiter characters.

Download the script from Github https://github.com/brablc/clit/blob/master/csv2xlsx.py. In order to run it you will need to install a python module **openpyxl** for Excel file manipulation: `sudo easy_install openpyxl`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case this worked (Mac, Excel 2011, both Cyrillic and Latin characters with Czech diacritics):

- Charset UTF-16LE (simply UTF-16 was not enough)
- BOM "\xFF\xFE"
- \t (tab) as separator
- Don't forget to encode also separator and CRLFs :-)
- Use iconv instead of mb_convert_encoding

Answer (score 2):

It seems to my case that Excel 2011 for Mac OS is not using Encoding.GetEncoding("10000") as i thought and wasted 2 days with but the same iso as on Microsoft OS.
The best proof for this is to make a file in Excel 2011 for MAC with special chars, save it as CSV and then open it in MAC text editor and the chars are scrambled.

For me this approach worked - meaning that csv export on Excel 2011 on MAC OS has special western europeean chars inside:

```
Encoding isoMacOS = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
Encoding defaultEncoding = Encoding.Default; 

// Convert the string into a byte array.
byte[] defaultEncodingBytes = defaultEncoding.GetBytes(exportText);

// Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
byte[] ansiBytes = Encoding.Convert(defaultEncoding, isoMacOS, defaultEncodingBytes);

decodedString = isoMacOS.GetString(ansiBytes);
```

Comment: What language are you using @user525081 ? Can you translate it to PHP?

Comment: @Timm that looks like a Java sample but in PHP you can use iconv to do the conversion - http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: OK @user525081, same deal as the other answers. This caters to Mac users, leaving Windows people in the lurch; and it doesn't answer the original question - an encoding that works on both platforms. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 with no BOM currently works for me in Excel Mac 2011 14.3.2.

UTF-8 + BOM kind of works, but BOM rendered as gibberish.

UTF-16 works if you Import the file and complete the wizard, but not if you just double-click it.

Answer (score 2):

On my Mac OS, Text Wrangler identified a CSV file created with Excel as having "Western" encoding.

After some googling I have made this small script (I am not sure about Windows availability, maybe with [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)?):

$ cat /usr/local/bin/utf8.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUTFILE="$1"

iconv -f macroman -c -t UTF-8 $INPUTFILE |tr '\r' '\n' >/tmp/file.$$.csv

mv $INPUTFILE ms_trash
mv /tmp/file.$$.csv $INPUTFILE
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me on OS X 10.14.2 (and Excel 2011)

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me on Excel for Mac 2011 and Windows Excel 2002:

1. Using iconv on Mac, convert the file to UTF-16 Little-Endian + name it *.txt (the .txt extension forces Excel to run the Text Import Wizard):

   `iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE filename.csv >filename_UTF-16LE.csv.txt`
2. Open the file in Excel and in the Text Import Wizard choose:

   - Step 1: *File origin*: ignore it, it doesn't matter what you choose
   - Step 2: select proper values for *Delimiters* and *Text qualifier*
   - Step 3: if necessary, select column formats

PS The UTF-16LE created by iconv has BOM bytes FF FE in the beginning.

PPS My original csv file was created on a Windows 7 computer, in UTF-8 format (with the BOM bytes EF BB BF in the beginning) and used CRLF line breaks. Comma was used as field delimiter and single quote as text qualifier. It contained ASCII letters plus different latin letters with tildes, umlaut etc, plus some cyrillic. All displayed properly in both Excel for Win and Mac.

PPPS Exact software versions:
* Mac OS X 10.6.8
* Excel for Mac 2011 v.14.1.3
* Windows Server 2003 SP2
* Windows Excel 2002 v.10.2701.2625

Comment: If you have a UTF-8 file without BOM, iconv will convert it to UTF-16LE **without** BOM (and unfortunately there is no way to tell iconv to add one)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

1. Open the file in BBEdit or TextWrangler*.
2. Set the file as Unicode (UTF-16 Little-Endian) (Line Endings can be Unix or Windows). Save!
3. In Excel: Data > Get External Data > Import Text File...

Now the key point, choose **MacIntosh** as File Origin (it should be the first choice).

This is using Excel 2011 (version 14.4.2)

*There's a little dropdown at the bottom of the window

Answer (score 1):

In my case adding Preamble to file solved my problem:

```
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv);
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(data).ToArray();
return File(new MemoryStream(result), "application/octet-stream", "data.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of csv, trying outputting html with an XLS extension and "application/excel" mime-type. I know this will work in Windows, but can't speak for MacOS

Comment: Thanks @royce23, but I'm just offering the CSV file for download. I can't present it through HTTP because the sheer size of the markup would slow the response to a crawl - the exported table may contain millions of rows...

Comment: with css your html would only be a tiny fraction larger than csv, for example: <r><c>id</c><c>name</c><c>phone</c></r>

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but I'm saving the CSV on the server and offering a download link. Generating an HTML response gobbles up too much PHP memory...

Comment: This will work (the UTF-8 chars) but if you have embedded line breaks within cells (`br` tag), Excel for Mac ignores the (works with Windows) CSS  `mso-data-placement:same-cell;`

Answer (score 0):

Solve this using java ( UTF-16LE with BOM ):

```
String csvReportStr = getCsvReport();
byte[] data = Charset.forName("UTF-16LE").encode(csvReportStr)
    .put(0, (byte) 0xFF)
    .put(1, (byte) 0xFE)
    .array();
```

Note that CSV file should use `TAB` as separator. You can read the CSV file both on windows and MAC OS X.

Refer to: [How do I encode/decode UTF-16LE byte arrays with a BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879482/how-do-i-encode-decode-utf-16le-byte-arrays-with-a-bom/880225#880225)