# parse csv file using php line by line

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file with data 
row 1 is header like this

```
 id fname lname email date code pid
```

each row then has data below each field name

```
3232456454  mike    strong  mike@mike.com   11/8/11 0:00    AU  2540
```

and when i see this csv using text editor, i see it as below.

```
3232456454,mike,strong,mike@mike.com,11/8/11 0:00,AU,2540
87876548788,bob,cool,bob@what.com,11/8/11 0:00,RY,2148
23498765,nike,tick,nike@google.com,11/8/11 0:00,TE,5240
```

Now i want to read the file using php and i want the data to be exactly same format as text file. I will use this data for other purpose as it is. I don't want to split at commas so i cannot use fgetcsv. I tried by just opening it using php file() but when i loop it, i don't see the proper data. Can some one please throw some suggestions?

if I do this way, it prints in the array with each element taking one value and I don't want this..

```
    $csv = array();
    $lines = file('sample.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
    {
        $csv[$key] = str_getcsv($value);
    } 
print_r($csv)
```

I tried using parsecsv library from google code but this is not really necessary as i want the data line by line.

I need to ignore the first line(header) in the output.

If i can get the output like this, this will solve my issues

```
Array
(
    [id,fname,lname,email,,data,code,pid] => 3232456454,mike,strong,mike@mike.com,11/8/11 0:00,AU,2540
)

Array
(
    [id,fname,lname,email,,data,code,pid] => 87876548788,bob,cool,bob@what.com,11/8/11 0:00,RY,2148
)
```

regards

Comment: What do you mean by "don't see proper data"? What *do* you see and what exactly do you expect?

Comment: hi, I see it as array format like this 

Array
(
    [0] => 3232456454
    [1] => mike
    [2] => strong
    [3] => mike@mike.com
    [4] => 11/8/11 0:00
    [5] => AU
    [6] => 2540
87876548788
    [8] => bob
    [9] => cool
    [10] => bob@what.com
    [11] => 11/7/11 0:00
    [12] => RY
    [13] => 2148
23498765

Comment: sorry, i don't know how to format the above data..so if you see, after 6th element, it takes the id of the next record. i want it as i see in the text file.

Comment: So, do you want it as an *array* or just as a line of text?

Comment: line of text, exactly as here
3232456454,mike,strong,mike@mike.com,11/8/11 0:00,AU,2540

so that i will get it line by line and when i reach the 50th record or something, i will do some other stuff...i can do the count and take care of once i get the data line by line. also, how can i skip the first line..?

Comment: First of all, why did you use FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES?

Comment: @favoretti i did that based on some example, thinking each line has the \n and now i see that i need not ignore this..

Comment: @favoretti You should consult the documentation for what exactly `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` does... :)

Comment: @deceze: Oops, indeed I should. Sleepy :) I should probably stop answering for today.

Comment: He says he already sees the array format from the `print_r` isnt this just a formatting issue?

Comment: You don't want to read the file using fgetcsv because you don't want to split on the commas, and then you split on the commas anyway using `str_getcsv()`? Yo dawg...

Comment: @deceze, please check my edits in the question..(last lines)

Answer (score 9):

```
$csv = file_get_contents($file);
```

This will get the file *as is* without any conversions or splitting or anything, just one long string.

If you want to split it into an array for each line, simply do

```
$csv = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

and nothing else. No looping, no `getcsv`, just `file()`.

---

But even if you say you're not interested in parsing the CSV, you *are* dealing with a CSV so I'd parse it as soon as possible and output it again, even back to CSV if necessary.

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
$header = fgetcsv($fh);

$data = array();
while ($line = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    $data[] = array_combine($header, $line);
}

fclose($fh);

print_r($data);


// outputting:

$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, array_keys($data[0])); // skip this if you don't want headers
foreach ($data as $line) {
    fputcsv($out, $line);
}
fclose($out);
```

If line endings aren't properly recognized, try `ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);` on top of your script.

See here for a demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/t31IEv

Comment: i did this 
$file = "smple.csv";
$csv = file_get_contents($file);
echo $csv;

just prints the last line..you should i don't have to loop, right?

Comment: @Jay `file_get_contents` gets the whole file at once, it should output more than just the last line.

Comment: i thought the same way, I just did what i pasted above but i see only last line..i am on mac not sure if that is an issue when i created the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Use fopen and fgets instead, and use a counter of which line you're at so you can ignore the first:

```
$c=0;
$data=fopen($file,'r');
while($row=fgets($data)){
    //$row is your line as a string
    if($c!=0){
    //do something with it
    echo $row."\n";
   }
   $c++;
}
```

Comment: where is your print line? if it's inside of the `if` (within the while) then it should fire each time

Answer (score 0):

If no matter what you do you can only get the last line of your CSV file using fgets() or fgetcsv(), simply try to copy/paste the content of your file to a new one and try using it instead.

I'm referring to the issue that @Jay seems to had: It seems that if the file was created with Excel 2011/Mac, its structure is not correctly interpreted.

See this for more info: [Which encoding opens CSV files correctly with Excel on both Mac and Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588068/which-encoding-opens-csv-files-correctly-with-excel-on-both-mac-and-windows)