# Unserialize MySQL field into outfile

Tags: php, mysql, file-io

I'm using MySQL OUTFILE to export a CSV of my database. I have a serialized field in there, and I was wondering if there was a way for me to unserialize it in the CSV using the MySQL query. I'm stumped!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean you serialized it with PHP. MySQL does not understand PHP serializing, AFAIK, so it can't. Plus, the serialized data I'm assuming is an array or object? This would most likely break the CSV file.

You're better off pulling the data from a query yourself, processing it and then using PHP's built in CSV handler functions to generate the CSV the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do it with mysql

**MySQL doesn't know what a PHP serialization is. You can't do it.**

you should have to make php serialization to do with your csv files

Comment: That's what I thought; is there a way for me to push something into the outfile with PHP? Or am I going to have to go an entirely different route with the CSV creation?

Comment: for that you have to post some code to get it clear, you can use serializ and unserializ function of PHP for your csv

Answer (score 0):

You essentially have two options:

1. Export from MySQL, and then use PHP to read and modify that file
2. Use PHP to access the database directly, and write your export file

While it *is* theoretically possible to create a MySQL stored procedure, or maybe a custom server extension, that would be capable of unserializing the PHP data, it would be a lot more difficult than just using PHP to do it.

It's not hard to write a small PHP program to modify a CSV file. Here is one answer that shows you a couple of examples: [parse csv file using php line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320372/parse-csv-file-using-php-line-by-line)

As for writing the code to access the database directly, that's in the PHP manual. You can see an example of how to read the database directly here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php