# Character encoding issue exporting rails data to CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding

I'm exporting data to a CSV file in rails and in some of my fields, I'm getting character encoding issues like this when I open in Excel:

```
didnâ€™t
```

I borrowed this code from an example and I'm assuming the encoding is off. Any idea what it should be?

```
send_data csv_data,
      :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
      :disposition => "attachment; filename=#{filename}.csv"
```

Comment: How is `csv_data` being generated? Rails usually defaults to UTF-8 so it may be enough to change it to `charset=utf-8;` in the second line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When Excel opens the CSV file it just assumes an "iso-8859-1" character encoding. I guess it doesn't even know about the encoding information you send along within your HTTP reply. That's why setting this to UTF-8 doesn't work.

So in order to export your CSV file for Excel in Rails you could do this:

```
send_data Iconv.conv('iso-8859-1//IGNORE', 'utf-8', csv_data),
  :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
  :disposition => "attachment; filename=#{filename}.csv"
```

This re-encodes your UTF-8 data string (that's the Rails default) to ISO-8859 and sends it. Along goes the information that this reply is actually ISO-8859-1 encoded (which won't make a difference for Excel but is technically correct if you should open it in a browser etc.).

Comment: With Ruby 1.9 you can handle the character encoding with the String class. Also the disposition default can be used. This results in a simpler: `send_data csv_string.encode("iso-8859-1"), :filename => fname, :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present'`

Comment: In my case the accepted answer did not work (Iconv constant not recognized). However, the solution proposed in the comment above worked just fine. I'm still up-voting this answer and the comment, since the overall idea of converting the string encoding is correct.

Comment: `Iconv` is deprecated as of Ruby 1.9.3. However, `send_data csv_string.encode("iso-8859-1"), :filename => fname, :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present'` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me, with Chinese characters!excel csv fromat (BOM + UTF8)

```
def export_csv_excel
  ....

  # Add BOM to make excel using utf8 to open csv file
  head = 'EF BB BF'.split(' ').map{|a|a.hex.chr}.join()

  csv_str = CSV.generate(csv = head) do |csv|
    csv << [ , , , ...]
    @invoices.each do |invoice|
      csv << [ , , , ...]
    end
  end

  send_data csv_str, filename: "Invoices-#{Time.now.strftime("%y%m%d%H%M%S")}.csv", type: "text/csv"
end
```

source(Chinese): http://blog.inheart.tw/2013/09/rubyraisl-csv-excel.html

Comment: Hi, can you explain how this works as CSV.generate(csv = head) accepts a hash? and where does the 'csv' come from? its haven't been defined yet?

Comment: ships with ruby. [ruby 1.9.3 csv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-headers)

Comment: require 'csv'  # add this!

Comment: It's working without `csv =` just `CSV.generate(head)`

Comment: More concise : `head = %w[EF BB BF].map { |a| a.hex.chr }.join`

Answer (score 10):

The answers above did not work for me on Mac Excel:
Using `iso-8859-1` would require I replace/remove weird characters, which is not a good enough solution for me, and using `BOM` with `UTF8` worked under Windows but not under Mac Excel.

What worked for me is the `WINDOWS-1252` encoding as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/20194266/226255

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  (CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << self.headers

    all.each do |e|
      csv << e.values
    end
   end).encode('WINDOWS-1252', :undef => :replace, :replace => '')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module DownloadService
  def student_list
   File.open("#{file_name}", "w+:UTF-16LE:UTF-8") do |f|
      file = CSV.generate({:col_sep => "\t"}) do |c| 
        c << ['Canción ', 'años', 'etc']
      end
      f.write "\xEF\xBB\xBF"
      f.write(file)
   end
  end
end
```