# Rails 4.2 - how to fix ascii code in CSV exporting without gem 'iconv'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

When exporting csv in Rails 4.2 app, there are ascii code in the csv output for Chinese characters (UTF8):

```
ä¸­åˆåŒç†Šå·¥ç­‰ç”¨é¤
```

We tried options in `send_data` without luck:

```
send_data @payment_requests.to_csv, :type => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present'
```

And:

```
send_data @payment_requests.to_csv.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

In model, there is forced encoding utf8:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

But it does not work. There are online posts talking about use gem `iconv`. However `iconv` depends on the platform's ruby version. Is there cleaner solution to fix the ascii in Rails 4.2 csv exporting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8873922/525478

Comment: What is the actual encoding of the data?

Comment: `@FrederickCheung`, I believe it is utf8 as Rails 4 default. There is a similar exporting method we used in Rails 3 app and Chinese characters were displayed correctly.

Comment: `@BradWerth`, the answer requires gem 'iconv'.

Comment: Those ASCII chars, are they shown by the browser or in an file editor?

Comment: I don't think you'll get any further without sharing the code that generates the csv.

Comment: what does `@payment_requests.to_csv.encoding` say and how is the text generated/loaded?

Comment: What are you opening the .csv in? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639153/character-encoding-issue-exporting-rails-data-to-csv

Answer (score 6):

If `@payment_requests.to_csv` includes ASCII text, then you should use `encode` method:

```
@payment_requests.to_csv.encode("UTF-8")
```

or

```
@payment_requests.to_csv.force_encoding("ASCII").encode("UTF-8")
```

depending on which internal encoding `@payment_requests.to_csv` has.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
@payment_requests.to_csv.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: No luck. even though it is a clean one.

Comment: Chinese characters? Maybe you need use UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1.

Comment: I recall that default char set of Rails is uft8. The same piece of code exports right csv file for Chinese characters. However it does not in Rails 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

for Chinese characters

```
CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
  csv << column_names
  all.each do |product|
    csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
  end
end.encode('gb2312', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
head = 'EF BB BF'.split(' ').map{|a|a.hex.chr}.join()

csv_str = CSV.generate(csv = head) do |csv|
  csv << [ , , , ...]
  @elements.each do |element|
    csv << [ , , , ...]
  end
end
```