# Set character encoding when generating CSV file Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, character-encoding, cjk, shift-jis

I have a module to generate csv file of the model when included.

```
# app/models/concerns/csv_exportable.rb
module CsvExportable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.to_csv(options = {})
      CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
        csv << column_names
        all.each do |thismodel|
          csv << thismodel.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and I include the module in models for which  I want to generate csv file

```
# app/models/product.rb
class Reason < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CsvExportable
  .
  .
end
```

In my controller I do

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv, filename: 'products.csv' }
end
```

I want to set the character encoding of generated csv file to [Shift_JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) instead of default utf-8. What is the best way to do this ? Thank you

**EDIT:**

I tried

```
format.csv { send_data (@products.to_csv).encode("SHIFT-JIS"), filename: 'products.csv' }
```

now I am getting an error `Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError   code converter not found (UTF-8 to SHIFT-JIS)`

Comment: **This can solve your problem** [When Excel opens the CSV file it just assumes an "iso-8859-1" character encoding. I guess it doesn't even know about the encoding information you send along within your HTTP reply. That's why setting this to UTF-8 doesn't work.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11451089/4209704)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
format.csv { 
  send_data (@products.to_csv).encode(Encoding::SJIS), 
  filename: 'products.csv', 
  type: 'text/csv; charset=shift_jis'
}
```

Did the trick

Comment: It's okay to accept your own answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `encoding: '<non utf-8 encoding>'` option in the `options` hash you passed to `to_csv` in `CsvExportable` so that it will be available for `CSV.generate` method while generating csv file.

Comment: Alredy tried that "unknown encoding name - SHIFT-JIS"