# Rails - Error when encoding CSV in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, encoding, export, activeadmin

Im using Active Admin with Rails and I'm exporting all my data in a csv file. It works really well in development, but in production i get this error :

**Encoding::UndefinedConversionError (U+00E7 to WINDOWS-1251 in conversion from UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1251)**

When I send_data :

```
date = DateTime.now
csv_title = "O535#{date.year}#{date.strftime('%m')}#{date.strftime('%d')}#{date.strftime('%H')}#{date.strftime('%M')}#{date.strftime('%S')}"

send_data csv.force_encoding('UTF-8'),
          :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
          :disposition => "attachment; filename=#{csv_title}.csv"
```

Has anyone ever met that error ? I tried using csv.encore / csv.force_encoding and many other solutions but it's still working well in development but always crash in production

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451089/400743

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn't work.
I found a solution by changing the way I used to generate my csv and now it works but I didn't find a solution for the problem above.
Thanks for trying to help me !