# create and save excel file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, npm

I am trying to create and save an excel file. I used this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-export)
and followed their example. In my case I want to save the result locally. Somehow like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile(filename, result,"binary");
```

I cannot open the file via excel, because it's saying that the file is corrupted or broken. Looking again at the example of the module, I know that `result` is in a binary format.

What can I do to parse `result` correctly for saving the excel file?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Take a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17450941/7028020). Similiar problem.

Comment: @Dario Thanks, but I tried this already. It didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you try some other node modules, for example like [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) or [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs)?

Comment: Thanks, I will research on the exceljs.