# Genrate Excel from XML with keys from different file adding value in same row

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I want to create node script which will convert XML to EXCEL file,I have different XML file I want to generate single EXCEL in key value pair, key is common and value is different in all files, I want to generate EXCEL in such way that it will take key in one column and values related to this keys in different column and in same row

File1.xml

```
<string name="app_name">PDF</string>
<string name="string_ok">English</string>
```

file2.xml

```
<string name="app_name">Share it</string>
<string name="string_ok">America</string>
```

file3.xml

```
<string name="app_name">File Explorer</string>
<string name="string_ok">India</string>
```

I want Excel in the following format

```
Key        column1   column2   column3
```

---

```
app_name   PDF       Share it  File Explorer
string_ok  English   America   India
```

Comment: Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890655/the-best-node-module-for-xml-parsing) for xml parsing. And checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450412/how-to-create-an-excel-file-with-nodejs) for creating excel files.