# How to export data from database to Excel? Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I use the Postgre database.

The user must select the date on the client and after that an  file Excel has been exported for the selected date.

So how can I, on the server side, export data from a database to Excel.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: @SanSolo In sense of? I wrote PostgreSQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an Excel File with Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450412/how-to-create-an-excel-file-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help. I've tried this in v10.6 and it is working fine

```
COPY "Table_Name" TO 'D:/sample.csv' (format csv);
```