# I want to manipulate xls file not xlsx with nodejs(js) any document

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to manipulate xls file not xlsx with nodejs(js) any document you can help me with

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you have?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and adjust your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It exists many js library for doing what you want.

I think that you need to check if library process xls file if already process xlsx file. It can be implicit...

You can try those libraries :

- exceljs ([exceljs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs))
- msexcel-builder ([msexcel-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msexcel-builder))
- excel4node ([excel4node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node))

You can read this previous post that dealing with those : [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450412/how-to-create-an-excel-file-with-nodejs)