# Date format in asp to excel form

Tags: excel, oracle, asp-classic

This is my original query, when i save my data records to excel file the date format from dd/mm/yyyy to d/m/yyyy, what can i do to change to the excel date format? Hope someone can help me..thanks ya..i hope the date can be dd/mm/yyyy.

```vb
strSQL2= "select DISTINCT to_char(PROD,'dd/mm/yyyy') as PROD_FORMATTED, to_char(PRAD,'dd/mm/yyyy') as PRAD_FORMATTED,PROD,PRAD, BRCH,DEPT,SANO,SUBM, to_char(SUBD,'dd/mm/yyyy') as SUBD, STAT, PSFG, TSAM, TLEV, CLEV, GROP, CTLV, CCLV, CRNM, EXFL FROM SANCTH " & _
         "where" & _
         sqlWhere2 & " ((cono,sano) in " & strFilterRole & " or crid='" & SQLEncode(StrCrid) & "')" & _
         "order by SUBD"
```

Some of the Excel output code;

```html
<td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=((objRS_Search("PROD_FORMATTED")))%></td>
<td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=((objRS_Search("PRAD_FORMATTED")))%></td>
<td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=((objRS_Search("BRCH")))%></td>
<td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=((objRS_Search("DEPT")))%></td>
<td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=((objRS_Search("SANO")))%></td>
```

I get "02/04/2014" in my excel. when i use the code below, it is remove every double quote and the date become 2/4/2014.how can it be 02/04/2014? need anyone's help, thank you very much!

```
  <td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=replace((("""" & objRS_Search("PROD_FORMATTED"))) & """",chr(34),"") %></td>
```

Comment: Here you go: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements004.htm

Comment: @DavidAldridge From this [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31647961/692942) I think the OPs issue is to do with how the date formats once displayed in Excel.

Comment: If you want the date format to be kept in Excel you will need to pass the field as a string.  So where you build up your Excel output you will need something like `"""" & YourDateFieldVariable & """"` to make sure it's passed as a string. It would help if you could post your Excel output code not just the Oracle SQL query.

Comment: @Lankymart i am not really sure what u say...what should i change in my query?

Comment: Changing your query will not help, the important part is where you build the Excel output, you need to make sure that the date field / variable is passed as a string to do that in Classic ASP you need to escape it in quotes `""""` will produce `"` when outputted.

Comment: @Lankymart u mean i have  to write " " " " & PROD_FORMATTED& " " " " in the excel output??

Comment: @Lankymart <td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=((objRS_Search("PROD_FORMATTED")))%></td> //this are a part ofmy excel output,so how should i put it inside?<td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=((objRS_Search(" " " " & PROD_FORMATTED& " " " ")))%></td> izit like this?

Comment: Yes, but would help to see the output code so I can advise better. If you building up a simple CSV and then outputting using `Response.ContentType` to set it to Excel then I'd expect something like `row = row & NumberField & ", """" & StringField & """""` etc. It's hard to explain without seeing your code.

Comment: Your not building it up like a CSV so that approach might not work but give it a try. Also add any code into your question using the Edit rather then pasting in comments as it's hard read.

Comment: all my coding? in which way that i can give u my coding?

Comment: Doesn't need to be **all** your coding just add the relevant bits to your question.

Comment: The most reliable format for sending dates to Excel, or any spreadsheet, is the ISO standard format of YYYY-MM-DD. I've never seen Excel OpenOffice, or GoogleSheets get it wrong.

Comment: td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=((objRS_Search("PROD_FORMATTED")))%></td>
   <td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=((objRS_Search("PRAD_FORMATTED")))%></td>
   <td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=((objRS_Search("BRCH")))%></td>
   <td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=((objRS_Search("DEPT")))%></td>
   <td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle"><%=((objRS_Search("SANO")))%></td>

Comment: @Lankymart something like this

Comment: @Lankymart but excel get it as d/m/yyyy , but i nid it to be dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @Lankymart how about any link for me to refer/

Comment: @DavidAldridge The issue is the OP wants the date to be formatted a certain way. To appear correctly in Excel the only way I know of is to send it as a string pre-formatted the way required. It's not that the date is passed incorrectly just the format is not what is required by the OP.

Comment: @Lankymart yes, u get me~

Comment: The problem with using a HTML table to trick Excel into creating the worksheet is I'm not sure how you can force a string to make sure your date format is correct. In the past I've done this using a string built CSV then setting the `Response.ContentType` to Excel's mime type and making sure to [correctly pass the BOM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24681290/692942) if data is not ASCII. Did you try `<%=(("""" & objRS_Search("PROD_FORMATTED"))) & """" %>`?

Comment: @Lankymart yes, i have try, but it is not working..any other solution?

Comment: @Lankymart hey i try again.it is okay with the date format ady! but yet the quotation is there, like this "02/01/2014"

Comment: @Lankymart i have try to remove a pair of " " but it's got error
..

Comment: Surely the presentation of the date format is a matter for the sheet to define. Internally they usually store dates as a number anyway -- "41234" etc.. The usual problem is getting the sheet to unambiguously recognise the data passed in as a date, and also to avoid dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy formats on import. I'm just saying that in my experience, YYYY-MM-DD is unambiguously interpreted as the correct date value, which can then be formatted for viewing in the desired way using spreadsheet functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td align="left" style="vertical-align:middle; mso-number-format:\@;"><%=(( objRS_Search("PROD_FORMATTED"))) %></td>
```

it is done when adding this `mso-number-format:\@;`

Comment: Post a new question and I'll try or someone else will.

Comment: If you have reach the question [asking limit](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited) then you should be looking at why and evaluating your existing questions. Limits are applied when you receive too many down-votes or close requests which commonly is due to questions; lacking adequate information, duplicating existing questions or failure to show basic attempt to address the problem (code examples). My advice would be first go back and assess your existing questions, if you have any marked as duplicate remove them.

Comment: The asking limit is there to educate you and is only temporary, any attempt to bypass this by asking other questions via comments shows a lack of respect for the system so my advice is ride it out and come back armed to write better questions in the near future.