# Unicode decode error with .csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, unicode, codec

I have what is probably a really basic Python question.

I'm trying to write a script that eliminates a bunch of blank rows in some .csv files, and the script I've written works on about 90% of my files, but a few throw the following error at me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stephensmith/Documents/Permits/deleterows.py", line 17, in <module>
    deleteRow(file, "output/" + file)
  File "/Users/stephensmith/Documents/Permits/deleterows.py", line 8, in deleteRow
    for row in csv.reader(input):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/encodings/utf_8_sig.py", line 69, in _buffer_decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 6540: invalid start byte
```

Here's my code:

```
import csv
import os

def deleteRow(in_fnam, out_fnam):
    input = open(in_fnam, 'r')
    output = open(out_fnam, 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for row in csv.reader(input):
        if any(row):
            writer.writerow(row)
    input.close()
    output.close()

for file in os.listdir("/Users/stephensmith/Documents/Permits/"):
    print(file)
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        deleteRow(file, "output/" + file)
```

I've tried adding encoding='utf-8', ='ascii', and ='latin1' to both of my open() statements, but no luck. :-( Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The .csv files were created with Excel for Mac 2011, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try looping through the csv files that are crashing with something like:

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        print repr(line)
```

to see if any suspicious characters are popping up.

If you were able to identify the suspicious characters this way, say *\0Xý1* pops up, you could clean the file by rewriting and replacing that character:

```
with open(file) as f:
    with open(file.rstrip(".csv") + "_fixed.csv") as g:
        for line in f:
            g.write(line.replace('\0Xý1', ''))
```

then try again with the cleaned file.

Answer (score 0):

It is an encoding issue. The input csv file is not utf-8 encoded as your Python platform would expect. The problem is that without knowing its encoding, nor having an example of an offending line, I really cannot guess the encoding.

It is normal that `encoding='utf8'` and `encoding='ascii'` both breaked because the offending character is 0xa2 which is not in the ascii range (<= 0x7f) not a valid utf-8 character. But it is really weird that `encoding='latin1'` gives same error at same place because 0xa2 is `¢` in latin1.

IMHO, per [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20194266/3545273), you could try `encoding='windows-1252'`, if it is supported by your platform.

If it still does not work, you should try to identify offending lines for `latin1` :

```
class special_opener:
    def __init__(self, filename, encoding):
        self.fd = open(filename, 'rb')
        self.encoding = encoding
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        return False
    def __next__(self):
        line = next(self.fd)
        try:
            return line.decode(self.encoding).strip('\r\n') + '\n'
        except Exception as e:
            print("Offending line : ", line, file = sys.stderr)
            raise e
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

def deleteRow(in_fnam, out_fnam):
    input = special_opener(in_fnam, 'latin1')
    output = open(out_fnam, 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for row in csv.reader(input):
        if any(row):
            writer.writerow(row)
    input.close()
    output.close()
```

The `special_opener` should output something like :

```
Offending line :  b'a,\xe9,\xe8,d\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
```

(this line is valid latin1, I got it with `special_opener(file, 'utf8')`)

Then you will be able to post the offending line here

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, the csv wasn't as large and opening it in LibreOffice Calc and saving it back fixed it.