# CSV exported from browser not displaying special character correctly on Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, browser, encoding

I am trying to export some data in csv format, it is fetched from my database (mongodb) with AJAX calls.

The problem is that special characters (e.g `é` `à`) are not displayed correctly in Excel after the CSV import.

However, they are correctly displayed on LibreOffice/Open Office, Google Spreadsheetm, and any text editor I could try.

I assume that the file is encoded in UTF-16 since it's generated from javascript.

Here's how I created the export in JavaScript (this is AngularJS) :

```
  $scope.downloadCityCSV = function() {
    $scope.csvURL = 'building';
    var data = 'email;first name;last name;Email confirmé;city;quantity;date\n';
    $scope.campaignData.cityVotes.forEach(function(vote) {
      var customer = vote.customer;
      data += customer.email +';' + customer.firstName +';' + customer.lastName +';' + (customer.accountConfirmed?"O":"N") +';' + vote.cityProposal + ';' + vote.quantity + ';' + vote.created + '\n';
    });
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type : 'text/csv' });
    $scope.csvURL = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
  };
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Which OS are you using? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588068/which-encoding-opens-csv-files-correctly-with-excel-on-both-mac-and-windows) may provide some insight.

Comment: I am using Mac OS Yosemite

Comment: Could you try to open the CSV with Excel on a Windows machine? Be sure to look at that question I posted, I think it'll answer your question.