# Encoding headaches with ' character in Python, Excel

Tags: python, csv, pandas, encoding, utf-8

I am reading a txt file into Python, extract parts of it and then output the results as CSV.

Problem is, I get encoding hiccups I don't know how to resolve. Here is what happens:

1. The input file is an export from Adobe Acrobat, where I output a "plain text file" after changing the setting to "UTF-8".
2. I then read this into Python like so

   ```
   inputfile=codecs.open(inputfile, "r", "utf-8")
   ```
3. I run a regex to extract parts of it, make them into a pandas `DataFrame` (called 'dataframe' here).
4. Then it write the dataframe out as a csv file, but no matter how I do it I run into problems. I tried

   ```
   outputfile=codecs.open(outputfile, "w", "utf-8")
   dataframe.to_csv(outputfile, encoding="utf-8")
   ```

but that gives me an

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 23:  ordinal not in range(128)
```

Question:

This is the first thing I don't get: why is there an 'ascii'-codec involved if I am setting the to_csv `encoding="utf-8"`? Acc to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), this is a

> A string representing the encoding to use in the output file, defaults to ‘ascii’ on Python 2...

I can avoid this error by not specifying "utf-8" in `codecs.open()`. But then, once I import the file into Excel (setting import to "Unicode-Utf-8"), all ' characters show up as __. There are no other encoding errors as far as I can see and if I open the csv file in TextWrangler, everything works out just fine.

- Where is the problem here -- is it the output from pandas, is it
  Excel, or what else?
- Is there a better way of tackling this?

I am working in Python 2 on a Mac. I did not use the Python csv module because it doesn't do UTF without a workaround.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
Here is what the inputfile looks like in WordWrangler:

> 23 
>    It’s lying down there on the floor.

Here is Excel:

> It__s lying down there on the floor.

After Fawful's helpful comment, I also tried to open the original text file in Excel. Seems like it already encodes the ' as __ in that one.

Answer (score 1):

Not a clean solution, but for a quick fix just use .replace('\0xe2', ' ').

Comment: Thanks, that would indeed work! I'd rather avoid that though as I have a couple more files to process and I'm afraid the hacks might accumulate...

Answer (score 1):

When writing the file from your pandas dataframe, do **not** use a `codecs` file object. `pandas.to_csv()` *already* encodes your data, and the `codecs` file object then has to try to decode (as ASCII) in order to be able to *re-encode* it.

Just use a regular file:

```
with open(outputfile, "w") as outputfile:
    dataframe.to_csv(outputfile, encoding="utf-8")
```

You can use the `csv` module as well, but then you have to encode all your row data to UTF-8 *before* passing the row to the `csv.writer().writerow()` function. The [`csv` module examples section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) includes code that automates this for you.

Comment: Thanks! I have a quick question re `(outputfile, "w", "utf-8")` -- this does not work for me, it asks for an "integer" instead. Can [open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) really take the "utf-8" setting? I couldn't find it in the docs either... If I get rid of the utf-8 part, things work but Excel still messes up in the same way. I'd think it's an issue with Acrobat's export, but then everything works just fine in WordWrangler...

Comment: @patrick: sorry, that was my mistake, a copy and paste error.

Comment: ah, okay! It's good to know about the pandas-encoding thing though. I'll give the csv module a try but beginning to think it's not really something that I am doing but Excel or Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

So looks like this is an Excel (at least Mac Excel 2011) issue; appears that while it does offer an "Unicode UTF-8" setting, it actually can't deal with unicode characters.

See e.g. this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588068/which-encoding-opens-csv-files-correctly-with-excel-on-both-mac-and-windows) and this [post](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304933-excel-for-mac/suggestions/9783765-support-utf-8-for-csv-import-export) from Microsoft. My files open just fine in Numbers. Didn't even know I had that on this machine...