# How do I specify the encoding of a text/CSV file when using ZK's `Filedownload.save()`?

Tags: download, character-encoding, httpresponse, zk

I have some reports in CSV format which I'd like to send to the browser as UTF-16LE to [make Excel happy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588068/which-encoding-opens-csv-files-correctly-with-excel-on-both-mac-and-windows) (well ... yeah).

When using ZK, I can pass `Filedownload.save()` a lot of information but how do I specify the encoding that should go in the response header?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to specify the encoding per download out of the box. ZK will only allow you to specify the encoding per file format by default. It works like this:

You have to create a `Media` instance with a format but without a `ctype` (content type). ZK will then look up the content type (plus the encoding) using `ContentTypes.getContentType()`.

In this case, that would be:

```
String bom = "\uFEFF";
AMedia media = new AMedia(filename, "csv", null, bom + dataAsString);
Filedownload.save(media);
```

Note: The `bom` is necessary to add the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the download so Excel will do the right thing. For other file formats, you don't need this.

To set the encoding, add a file `contentTypes.properties` to your classpath (put it in `src/main/resources/` when using Maven):

```
csv=text/csv;charset=UTF-16LE
```

ZK will parse this file during startup. When a `Media` object without content type but with format `csv` is being processed, ZK will set the content type to `text/csv;charset=UTF-16LE` in `AMedia.setup()`.

The other option is to create your own implementation of the `Media` interface which doesn't strip the `charset` part from the content type.

Related:

- https://donatstudios.com/CSV-An-Encoding-Nightmare