# Saving UTF-8 CSV for Windows and Mac

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filesaver.js

I have a web application that generates a UTF-8 .csv and returns it to the user with the following code.

```
const createCSV = () => {

  ...

  return new Blob(["\ufeff" + csvContent], {
            type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8",
        })
}
```

I had to add the `\ufeff` BOM in order to get the `≤` character to render correctly in Excel

I am using Filesaver.js to trigger the save to the user's computer

```
onClick={() => saveAs(createCSV(attributes), "template.csv", {autoBom: true})}
```

This seems to work fine for Mac users, but when a user on Windows clicks the download button, the download prompt is showing the file type as `Unicode Text`.

Any ideas why the file is showing up as `Unicode Text` instead of `.csv` for Windows users?

Comment: Does it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588068/which-encoding-opens-csv-files-correctly-with-excel-on-both-mac-and-windows ?

Comment: I tried it out using `new TextEncoder("windows-1252", {NONSTANDARD_allowLegacyEncoding: true,}).encode(csvContent)`, which saves the file correctly but now the `≤` is saved as an unknown character

Comment: Thats because there is no such character in windows-1252 not much to deal with that

Comment: Hmm okay, I will need to look for an encoding that works for both windows and mac and supports that character. Thanks for the suggestion though