# Right way to deal with Unicode BOM in a text file

Tags: java, file-io, character-encoding, guava

I am reading a text file in my program which contains some Unicode BOM character `\ufeff`/`65279` in places. This presents several issues in further parsing.

Right now I am detecting and filtering these characters myself but would like to know if Java standard library or Guava has a way to do this more cleanly.

Comment: In _places_? The BOM should be the first bytes of a file; otherwise it isn't a BOM.

Comment: Assuming that the BOM is at the start of the file then [this](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=345&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary) bug report of the Guava website explains that Guava doesn't handle BOM and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736999/how-to-remove-bom-from-an-xml-file-in-java) post gives an idea on how to skip it in plain Java.

Comment: @bmorris591, yes, in the beginning. Thanks. If you post your 2nd comment as an answer, I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no built in way of dealing with a (UTF-8) BOM in Java or, indeed, in Guava.

There is currently a bug report on the [Guava website](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=345&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary) about dealing with a BOM in Guava IO.

There are several SO posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736999/how-to-remove-bom-from-an-xml-file-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java)) on how to detect/skip the BOM while reading a file in plain Java.

Your BOM (`\ufeff`) seems to be [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) which, according to the same Guava report *should* be dealt with automatically by Java. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879482/how-do-i-encode-decode-utf-16le-byte-arrays-with-a-bom) SO post seems suggest the same.