# Is it possible to construct an Yylex object by using an String?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer, jflex

Recently i've been working with Jflex and i noticed that when i try to construct the Yylex object it only accepts `java.io.Reader` and `java.io.InputStream`. How could i do if i just want to build the object by using only a String?, like this:

```
String myString = "Hello world";
String token;
Yylex scanner = new Yylex(myString);

while ((token = scanner.yylex()) != null) {
     //do something
}
```

In the system i'm trying to build i want the user to write something and then apply the Yylex method to it. In the models i saw that were similar to my idea the user inputs an String and then it is written into a file from where the Yylex will read.

Is it possible to do that? or i'm misunderstanding something?. Is there any other tool you would reccomend instead of Jflex?

Thanks!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837703/how-can-i-get-a-java-io-inputstream-from-a-java-lang-string

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do want you want would be to use a `StringReader`, which creates a reader from a String without any other hoops to jump through. Simply use:

```
Yylex scanner = new Yylex(new StringReader(myString));
```